# Creating excel workbook using excel worksheet (with required condition) using python

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have 8 excel files in directory. Out of those 8 excel files, I want to create an excel workbook using few worksheet (only few) and then create another workbook using rest worksheet. I have written the code as follows -

```
from pathlib import Path  # Standard Python Module
import time  # Standard Python Module
import xlwings as xw  # pip install xlwings

# Adjust Paths
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).parent
SOURCE_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'Region'
OUTPUT_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'Output'

# Create output directory
OUTPUT_DIR.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
# Using 5 excel files from the 8 excel file list as mentioned above
include_ws = ['US-CAN ABS','US-CAN CMBS RMBS','US-CAN CDO','US-CAN Cov Bonds','Reason Codes Description']

excel_files = Path(SOURCE_DIR).glob('*.xlsx')

# Create timestamp
t = time.localtime()
timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H%M', t)

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    combined_wb = app.books.add()
    for excel_file in excel_files:
        wb = app.books.open(excel_file)
        for sheet in wb.sheets:
            if sheet.name in include_ws:
                sheet.copy(after=combined_wb.sheets[0])
            wb.close()
        combined_wb.sheets[0].delete()
        combined_wb.save(OUTPUT_DIR / f'all_worksheets_{timestamp}.xlsx')
        combined_wb.close()
```

Getting following error

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'A workbook must contain at least one visible worksheet. \n\nTo hide, delete, or move the selected sheet(s), you must first insert a new sheet or unhide a sheet that is already hidden.', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: You should always provide the full Traceback, don't assume people can tell which line an error occurred, and there may be other useful information  needed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the error means you are trying to delete the one and only sheet in a workbook and that is not possible. It doesn't look like you are making any checks before trying to do the deletion.
I.e
You create the workbook 'combined_wb' and then if a sheet from 'wb' is in your list 'include_ws' copy across. However if none are, then no sheets are copied across to 'combined_wb' so it remains with just 'Sheet1'. Then you try to delete 'Sheet1', not possible because as the error says ***'A workbook must contain at least one visible worksheet.***'
You should confirm there were sheets copied before invoking the delete line.